# JSON = "XXX is Null or not an Object" in ie6, ie7 (not ie8, FF, Ch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why am I getting an error in my json use in ie6 and ie7, but no other browser?

I'm parsing with:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.brettbarros.com/wordpress/?post_type=projects&json=get_post&include=title,content,attachments&post_id=8', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I'm parsing a json feed from the wordpress plugin JSON API:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

**You can view a test / error here: http://brettbarros.com/ietest.html**

Edit 2: It appears that "data" is null. I have no idea why.

Edit 3: Here are my headers... anyone see any problems with them? If so, how would I fix it?

```
Date    Mon, 26 Jul 2010 08:31:11 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.7a mod_fcgid/2.3.5 Phusion_Passenger/2.2.15 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.13
X-Pingback  http://brettbarros.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="json_api.json"
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  719
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=98
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Look at the headers of the request, what are they telling you.

Comment: GET /wordpress/?post_type=projects&json=get_post&include=title%2Ccontent%2Cattachments&post_id=8 HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: www.brettbarros.com[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.36 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]

Comment: I got US-Iran relations project or something similar before you changed the code in Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: Thanks anders. I've got it working in ie7 now, but not ie6. Here is a test page that illustrates the json file not loading: 

http://brettbarros.com/ietest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seams that the Javascript engine doesn't see a url property in the attachment. So if you expect a  url property there and this only doesn't work in IE6 and IE7 the execution off the JSON request doesn't go well. Maybe the parameters are not correct or `id` isn't a good value in the browsers?

Where is `id` being set?

Do you debug the JSON request to see if in each browser `id` is set?

maybe you can give more information?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it might have something to do with the actual json file that I'm calling or how I'm calling it? Does ie6/7 need a .js ending or something?

Comment: I've added a url for you to test

Comment: Just put an alert(id) before the $.getJSON( to see if id is set. I think setting the id is the problem. Handling the JSON-request is doing serversided... And that doesn't seems to give any problems. I get a good response over here

Comment: Thanks michael, but I even tried hardcoding the id and it's still no good.

Comment: Aha! It was a combination of subdomain www having cross domain issues *and* id being wrong. Thanks a billion :)